# Google Chart Add Each Day on the between SQL String

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, google-visualization

This is the code

```
$search_sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE from_unixtime(timestamp, '%e %b %Y') BETWEEN '$from_date_string' AND '$to_date_string' ";

$search_result = mysql_query($search_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$search_total = mysql_num_rows($search_result);

var dataTable2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ["Date From", "Result"],
  ["' . $from_date_string .'",  ' . $search_total2 . '],
  < INSERT LOOP EACH DATE BETWEEN HERE >
  ["' . $to_date_string .'",  ' . $search_total3 . ']
]);
```

Basically i would like to add the Inbetween Days into the Google Chart DataTable2 inbetwen the From and the To.

I figure that it would be a foreach record, but am lost as to where to start.

Date Format Example - 1 Jan 13

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($search_result_loop)){
echo "['Date',  200], \n";
}
```

I need this bit above to give me each day between the From and To dates

Comment: Looking at your code, I recommend not using the mysql API. It has been depreciated since the 5.5.0 release of PHP, and the PHP development team has announced that the mysql extension will be removed and no longer supported. The alternative route would be to look into using mysqli (mysql improved) or PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the query to group results by date, eg:

```
select 
    from_unixtime(timestamp, '%e %b %Y') as somedate, 
    count(*) as 'searchtotal'
from logs
where from_unixtime(timestamp, '%e %b %Y') BETWEEN '$from_date_string' AND '$to_date_string'
group by somedate
```

Comment: This results in Unknown column 'somedate' in 'where clause'

Comment: Answer edited to remove quotes from alias and avoid alias in where clause.